# Can I use python with statement for conditional execution?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm trying to write code that supports the following semantics:

```
with scope('action_name') as s:
  do_something()
  ...
do_some_other_stuff()
```

The scope, among other things (setup, cleanup) should decide if this section should run.
For instance, if the user configured the program to bypass 'action_name' than, after Scope() is evaluated do_some_other_stuff() will be executed without calling do_something() first.
I tried to do it using this context manager:

```
@contextmanager
def scope(action):
  if action != 'bypass':
    yield
```

but got `RuntimeError: generator didn't yield` exception (when `action` is `'bypass'`).
I am looking for a way to support this without falling back to the more verbose optional implementation:

```
with scope('action_name') as s:
  if s.should_run():
    do_something()
    ...
do_some_other_stuff()
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

P.S. I am using python2.7

EDIT:
The solution doesn't necessarily have to rely on `with` statements. I just didn't know exactly how to express it without it. In essence, I want something in the form of a context (supporting setup and automatic cleanup, unrelated to the contained logic) and allowing for conditional execution based on parameters passed to the setup method and selected in the configuration.
I also thought about a possible solution using decorators. Example:

```
@scope('action_name') # if 'action_name' in allowed actions, do:
                      #   setup()
                      #   do_action_name()
                      #   cleanup()
                      # otherwise return
def do_action_name()
  do_something()
```

but I don't want to enforce too much of the internal structure (i.e., how the code is divided to functions) based on these scopes.
Does anybody have some creative ideas?

Comment: `with` is not `if` ... you can write `s.do_something()` and have the contextmanager return a object that does nothing.

Comment: Thought about it too, but I still hope to find an elegant solution...

Comment: Also, I don't know anything about the code inside this scope (e.g., do_something()) in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to modify the expected behaviour of a basic language construct. That's never a good idea, it will just lead to confusion.

There's nothing wrong with your work-around, but you can simplify it just a bit.

```
@contextmanager 
def scope(action): 
  yield action != 'bypass'

with scope('action_name') as s: 
  if s: 
    do_something() 
    ... 
do_some_other_stuff()
```

Your `scope` could instead be a class whose `__enter__` method returns either a useful object or `None` and it would be used in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks.    
(Not trying to start a debate about python context semantics here, ) I disagree with the "expected behavior of a basic language construct" part. For me, it was very clear that the 'yield' part of a contextmanager ma be skipped. Until I caught the "didn't yield" exception.
I think the language should have taken care of it, maybe by throwing a predefined exception type from __enter__, similarly to the StopIteration exception for the next() method.

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def skippable():
    try:
        yield
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if e.message != "generator didn't yield":
            raise

@contextmanager
def context_if_condition():
    if False:
        yield True

with skippable(), context_if_condition() as ctx:
    print "won't run"
```

Considerations:

- needs someone to come up with better names
- `context_if_condition` can't be used without `skippable` but there's no way to enforce that/remove the redundancy
- it could catch and suppress the RuntimeError from a deeper function than intended (a custom exception could help there, but that makes the whole construct messier still)
- it's not any clearer than just using @Mark Ransom's version

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done. I tried implementing a context manager as a class and there's just no way to *force* the block to raise an exception which would subsequently be squelched by the `__exit__()` method.

Comment: I had that feeling. I hoped it can be solved using some of that python magic I usually find on those cases. Seems like a nice functionality, though. Maybe I can request it as an enhancement... :)

Answer (score -2):

I have the same use case as you, and came across the [conditional library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/conditional/1.1) that someone has helpfully developed in the time since you posted your question.

From the site, its use is as:

```
with conditional(CONDITION, CONTEXTMANAGER()):
    BODY()
```

Comment: This is not a solution. the `conditional` library applies the condition to whether or not the given *context manager* is entered. The body is always executed regardless.