# An elegant way to use a resource in Python?

Tags: python

I want to find an elegant way to do the following:

```
try:
    with some_resource:
        # got it
        do_something()

except ResourceUnavailableError:
    # didn't get it
    do_something_else()
```

This:

1. tries to get a resource
2. on success, it does something, and then releases the resource correctly
3. on failure, it does something else

Although not many lines of code, I find that if I have to keep writing this in many different places, it's not very elegant.

I almost wish I could write something as follows (I know this is not real Python code):

```
with some_resource:
    # got it
    do_something()

# an optional else
else:
    # didn't get it
    do_something_else()
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to write something along those lines in Python?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

No, `with` has no `else` block. But you can write your own context manager that handles the `else` part:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def handle_unavailable(resource, exception, exception_handler):
    try:
        with resource:
             yield resource
    except exception:
        exception_handler()
```

and use it like this everywhere as:

```
with handle_unavailable(some_resource, ResourceUnavailableError, do_something_else):
    do_something()
```

So if `ResourceUnavailableError` is raised in the `with` block, `do_something_else` is called for you.

This makes use of the [`@contextlib.contextmanager()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager), which makes writing your own context managers almost trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  But... I'm not sure that this works.  I tried coding it in, and when no exception was raised, all was good.  But if an exception was raised, then after running exception_handler(), I got: RuntimeError: generator didn't yield.

Comment: BTW, this error led me to another, similar post here, which also seemed to have ended in misery :P

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314338/can-i-use-python-with-statement-for-conditional-execution

Comment: Ah, crumbs. Indeed, I assumed you meant the exception would be raised in the `with` block, not in creating the resource.